# capturing images on tablets with dual webcams

Tags: c#, webcam

I have built an application that will capture and upload images taken from a tablet webcam to a database, the app works on tablets that only have one webcam but refuses to load the driver from tablets that have dual webcams. The code I'm using is straight from another code project solution, I'm using code from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/536314/WhatplusisplususingplusWinFormCharpWebCam-b)

Does anybody know if there is a fix for tablets sporting dual webcams?

```
public void Start(ulong FrameNum)
{
    try
    {
        // for safety, call stop, just in case we are already running
        this.Stop();

        // setup a capture window
        mCapHwnd = capCreateCaptureWindowA("WebCap", 0, 0, 0, m_Width, m_Height, this.Handle.ToInt32(), 0);

        // connect to the capture device
        Application.DoEvents();
        SendMessage(mCapHwnd, WM_CAP_CONNECT, 0, 0);
        SendMessage(mCapHwnd, WM_CAP_SET_PREVIEW, 0, 0);

        // set the frame number
        m_FrameNumber = FrameNum;

        // set the timer information
        this.timer1.Interval = m_TimeToCapture_milliseconds;
        bStopped = false;
        this.timer1.Start();
    }

    catch (Exception excep)
    { 
        MessageBox.Show("An error ocurred while starting the video capture. Check that your webcamera is connected properly and turned on.\r\n\n" + excep.Message); 
        this.Stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say "refuses to load the driver:" Are you getting an error message, or exceptions thrown? What are they and what line of code do they occur on?

Comment: The error occurs in the WebCam_Capture.dll coding which I found and it has an if statement which tests output from SendMessage(mCapHwnd, WM_CAP_CONNECT, 0, 0);

Comment: You still haven't described what the error is. Is there a code, message, etc?

Comment: The error is "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: Well, that's generally a fairly easy one to diagnose, at least. Can you post the code that generates it? I'm guessing `WebCam_Capture.dll` is a third party component that you've decompiled?

Comment: At what line does the error occur? What does the stack trace look like?